# FileWriter API: use blob to write data

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

i have a blob url like `blob:blahblah` that points to a file. I want to write the file behind this blob to local filesystem. The `writer.write()` documentation says it accepts a file object (from input-type-file) *and* a blob. But it throws a type mismatch error when  try this

```
fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
    writer.write(blob); //blob is a var with the value set to the blob url
```

i know the problem is that the `blob` does not get accepted but i would like to know how can i store a blob to the filesystem. i created the said blob earlier in the script from input-type-file and stored it's value in a var.

**EDIT**

Ok so i think i should have given more code in the first place.

first i create a blob url and store it in a var like this

```
files[i]['blob'] = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
```

`files` is from an input-type-file html tag and i is looped for number of files. you know the gig.

then the variable goes through a number of mediums, first through chrome's message passing api to another page and then from that page to a worker via `postMessage` and then finally back to the parent page via `postMessage` again.

on the final page i intend to use it to store the blob's file to local file system via file system api like this..

```
//loop code
fileSystem.root.getFile(files[i]['name'], {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
        writer.write(files[i]['blob']);
    });
});
//loop code
```

but the `writer.write` throws `Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM File Exception 11`

i believe this error is because the variable supplied to `writer.write` is a text and not a blob object from something like `createObjectUrl` (directly and not after passing through multiple pages/scopes) or not a `window.WebKitBlobBuilder`. So how can a blob's url be used to store a file?

Comment: browser, version and error text, please.

Comment: file api only works in chrome. version is stable and error does not matter because it is a valid error, i am looking for a way to do it correctly. anyways.. `TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR`

Comment: I don't see such error in the spec, - so either ther spec is outdated, or you are doing something wrong, or there is a bug in chrome. http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html

Comment: I've had success saving blobs to the FS. How are you creating the blob? This example works for me: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-example-savingimages

Comment: @ebidel i use `createObjectURL` to create blobs. the blobs work when i paste the url in the url bar. and in that example, the blob is created on the fly.. i have a variable whose value is blob url. i think those are two different cases. an array buffer is appended to a blank blob in that example, i use `createObjectURL` to create blobs from input files and store them in a variable for later use. the variable is just text and not a blob object. its a text of blob's url.

Comment: @c69 the error is on this page, apparently file api and file system api are diffrent. :O http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#widl-FileError-TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR

Comment: maybe try using **blobBuilder** ? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing

Comment: @c69 where should i use it? should i try using it instead of `createObjectURL`? (well doing that now, but i dont think it should make any difference because both create blobs) or should i use it where i write the file in fs? i did try that but i cant figure out how can i create a blob from the blob url (i.e. no file object) if later is the case then can you write some rudimentary code? that would be super helpful.. just a couple of lines on how can i use a variable and append its source file to a blobBuilder. (i tried giving the url variable to the `.append()` function but it didnt work) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edited code snippet and description, it sounds like you're writing the blobURL to the filesystem rather than the `File` itself (e.g. `files[i]['name']` is a URL). Instead, pass around the `File` object between main page -> other page -> worker -> main page. As of recent (in Chrome at least), your round trip [is now possible](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/09/Workers-ArrayBuffer). `File` objects can be passed to `window.postMessage()`, whereas before, the browser serialized the argument into a string.

You 'fashion' a handler/reference to a `Blob` with `createObjectURL()`. There's not really a way to go from blobURL back to a `Blob`. So in short, no need to create `createObjectURL()`. Just pass around `files[i]` directly.

Comment: but these are for workers only.. right? (i.e. will file objects go through chrome's message passing api? [they didn't go that last time i checked but it was a couple weeks ago and maybe there is some change in latest nightly builds]) my file object first go from index page to background page and then to the worker.. it made sense to implement worker in background page but i can move it to index if there is no other way.. :O

Comment: Yep, you can pass File objects to Workers now.

Comment: hmm you seem to have misunderstood :( i know we can do it now, what i am asking is can i send them from index page to background page with chrome's message passing api? coz file objects are created on index page but worker is on background page :)